# Must I always have to restart the Tomcat server to clear out Velocity Template cache?

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, jira, velocity

What I am doing is directly modifying a .vm file in our Jira project on my test server trying to figure out a bug that we have. The reason why I am doing this directly on the server is because our project build time and start-up of the server is over 10 minutes for every build (thats another issue for another day).

After modifying the .vm file I have tried to clear out the cache on Tomcat by completely deleting the `Catalina\localhost\projectName` folder as well as the browser cache. This does not work and I am forced to shutdown the Tomcat server and restart and only then do the changes show up.

Sick of shutting down and starting back up to test each change I am making in the file to troubleshoot.

**Is there another way I can do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging, you should be able to turn caching off.  If you're loading templates as files, for example, you could set the following property in your config:

```
file.resource.loader.cache=false
```

Comment: Bear with me please, but I just checked all of the files in the Tomcat conf folder; catalina.policy, catalina.properties, context.xml, logging.properties, server.xml, tomcat-users.xml and web.xml and am unable to find the setting file.resource.loader.cache anywhere. What config file are you referring?

Comment: How are you setting any of the Velocity configuration parameters?

Comment: I don't know anything about Velocity and I kid you not when I say every developer has abandoned ship on this project. I have nobody to reach out to that was on this project. Last man standing here :)

Comment: Within your JIRA Install folder is `atlassian-jira\WEB-INF\classes\velocity.properties` which is where you would add property.

Comment: Ok thank you both for your help. I found the file and the lines near the top of the file. `class.recource.loader.cache=true`. Now to continue on.

Comment: I have not been able to disable my Velocity caching of macros. The only hack I've figured out is to rename the macro that I'm working on. I wish there were a better way. P.S. https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/disable-velocity-caching/ is kind of related.